# Metodo Set con punteros y new, C++, relaciones de clases,manipulacion de punteros

Tags: c++, poo

Trabajo en VS 2017, estoy un poco confundido a la hora de manipular punteros entre clases, este es mi codigo resumido,[EDIT], al parecer la pregunta es escueta, daré un ejemplo más concreto con más métodos para esclarecer

```
    Class A{
    private:
     string nom;

    public:
    A(){
     nom = "-";
     }
     void setNom(string pnom){
      nom = pnom;}
    ~A(){}
   };

   Class B{
   private:
     A* atributodeA;

   public:
    A(){
     atributodeA = NULL;
     }
     void setValorA(A* _a){
      atributodeA = _a;}
     A* devuelveA(){ return atributodeA;}

    ~A(){
     delete atributodeA;}
```

Necesito crear una tercera clase que tenga como atributo a la clase B(digamos un vector de B) y que contenga un método que cuando se invoque cambie el valor de "atributodeA", esta es mi idea en el main:

```
    int main(){
     //
     string auxnom;
     A* ptrA = new A;
     B* ptrB = new B;

     cin>>auxnom;
     ptrA->setNom(auxnom);
     ptrB->setValorA(ptrA);//[EDIT]
     //cout<<B->devuelvaA(); el programa da error aqui

     delete ptrA;
     delete ptrB;

    }
```

El metodo en teoria deberia llamarse las veces que sea necesario, el programa al compilar alerta de una excepcion de lectura y una direccion de memoria
Toda la ayuda es bienvenida

Comment: Buenas y bienvenido a [es.SO]. Para que te podamos ayudar, necesitaríamos un esbozo de lo que quieres realizar para ir indicándote.
Dices que necesitas crear una tercera clase, pero no la veo. ¿Podrías crear el esqueleto de dicha clase? Desde ahí, podremos indicarte mejor.

Comment: ¿Y por qué motivo omites constructores y destructores? Lo mismo el problema está justamente ahí...

Comment: @eferion en el ejemplo, la memoria dinámica es creada y destruida externamente, dado que `B` no parece gestionar `A *` no sería necesario hacer nada en el destructor de `B`.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster dado que B tiene una instancia de A **puede** que el destructor de B provoque un doble borrado junto con el `delete ptrA`

Comment: Pero no sucede porque `B` no tiene destructor.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster el propio OP reconoce que **"omite constructores, etc..."**, con eso entiendo que existir existen... pero que no los publica en la pregunta

Comment: Ah, yo entendía que los omite por diseño, no por brevedad de código.

Comment: He añadido mas información al código si lo quieren revisar @JoséManuelRamos

Comment: Observa bien que en la clase B borras el atributo A, pero no creas ninguno. El resto correspondería a lo que ha expresado @eferion.

Comment: @JoséManuelRamos sí crea uno, `ptrB->setValorA(ptrA);` es equivalente a hacer `ptrB->atributodeA = ptrA`. En cualquier caso `delete 0` o, si lo prefieres,  `delete NULL` no producirá errores en el sistema (por si se le olvidase asignar algo a `atributodeA`)

Answer (score 2):

```
Class B{
   private:
     A* atributodeA;

   public:
    ~B(){ delete atributodeA; }
};

int main()
{
    A* ptrA = new A;
    B* ptrB = new B;

    ptrB->setValorA(ptrA);

    delete ptrA;
    delete ptrB;
}
```

El problema lo tienes en los dos últimos `delete`.

Antes de liberar la memoria tienes lo siguiente:

```
                     Dirección de memoria (supuesto)
ptrA                   0x1000
ptrB                   0x2000
ptrB->atributodeA      0x1000
```

Lo primero que haces es liberar `ptrA`, luego el sistema liberará esa memoria (`0x1000`).

A continuación liberas `ptrB` y aquí empiezan los problemas. Si te fijas en el destructor de `B`, el mismo ejecuta un `delete` sobre `atributodeA`... un puntero que apunta a la dirección `0x1000`, memoria que **ya ha sido liberada**.

Los Sistemas Operativos modernos detectan los intentos de acceso a memoria para evitar que un proceso modifique la memoria que no le pertenece (y que potencialmente podría estar siendo utilizada por otros procesos). Este proceso existe para evitar la corrupción de memoria.

La solución es tan sencilla como eliminar `delete ptrA`. Puesto que el objeto apuntado por `ptrB` ya se está encargando de gestionar el ciclo de vida del objeto apuntado por `ptrA`, no es necesario liberar el recurso *a mano*:

```
int main()
{
    A* ptrA = new A;
    B* ptrB = new B;

    ptrB->setValorA(ptrA);

    delete ptrB;
}
```